A very short story about a painting that took the life of the model
I read this very short fantasy-horror story several decades ago, probably in a collection but I don't remember anything else about that book.
The POV character finds himself (he is definitely male) in a room where many paintings hang on the walls, all representing people. I don't remember how he got there. Not a public museum, rather a family private collection. In the room there is also a booklet telling the story of each painting.
He is fascinated by the painting of a woman of extraordinary beauty. The story was that the model was the wife (or maybe just the sweetheart ?) of the painter. The latter was obsessed with the idea of a perfect painting. So he kept painting day and night to reach perfection. While the model felt she was getting weaker and weaker, because of her love for the painter she allowed her life to be "sucked into" the painting and she died the instant when the painter finally reached perfection.

This is The Oval Portrait by Edgar Allen Poe.
The tale (approx two pages long, and which can be read in full here) depicts a story-within-a-story about a painter's wife and his obsession with painting her.

The book describes a tragic story involving a young maiden of "the rarest beauty". She loved and wedded an eccentric painter who cared more about his work than anything else in the world, including his wife. The painter eventually asked his wife to sit for him, and she obediently consented, sitting "meekly for many weeks" in his turret chamber. The painter worked so diligently at his task that he did not recognize his wife's fading health, as she, being a loving wife, continually "smiled on and still on, uncomplainingly". As the painter neared the end of his work, he let no one enter the turret chamber and rarely took his eyes off the canvas, even to watch his wife. After many weeks had passed, he finally finished his work. As he looked at the completed image, however, he felt appalled, as he exclaimed, "This is indeed Life itself!" Thereafter, he turned suddenly to regard his bride and discovered that she had died.


Wow ! That was fast ! Indeed all the details in the Wiki page fit my memories. The sentence "This is indeed Life itself!" definitely strikes a bell. Seven more minutes before  I can accept it...

@Alfred - My apologies for taking so long. I'd have posted it sooner but I was enjoying re-reading it :-)

"for taking so long" LOL !

Does the story have any science-fictional or fantastical elements?

@user14111 - Not overtly. The relationship between the 'uncannily lifelike' painting and the deteriorating health of the wife were the inspiration for the far more obviously on-topic Portrait of Dorian Gray

@user14111 - You might want to raise this one on Meta. I'm borderline on it. The implication is that he's drawing out her life-force in some respect ("he would not see that the tints which he spread upon the canvas were drawn from the cheeks of her who sate beside him.") but it's not spelled out for us.

Mostly unrelated: it's actually The Picture of Dorian Grey. I always think it's "portrait" and then have to remind myself. Not sure why, but I think "portrait" would make a better title.

@ToddWilcox Maybe Wilde used "picture" deliberately to blur the distinction of being owned by Grey or depicting Grey (both are true).

I like my version better. I confess I've never read  it past the first few boring pages.

@Valorum I wonder if your mistake is due to the French title which is indeed "Le Portrait de Dorian Gray".

@Alfred - I must confess that I didn't read it in French. That being said, you have not experienced Wilde until you have read him in the original Klingon

@Valorum But of course ! The Klingon of Lady Windermere, looking for her fan, is really exquisite...

IIRC in the book/movie the ITEM was often referred to as a portrait, but both titles were "Picture."  This may explain the apparent Mandela effect.

@CristobolPolychronopolis - Sure, or possibly I'm just ill-educated and only vaguely remember the title because it was in a Simpsons episode.

@Valorum You're not the only one...I thought the movie used "portrait" in the title until I looked it up.  Many other people remember the book, movie, or both titled with "portrait," but they both use "picture" IRL.
